# Download CSV File using PHP curl with login credentials

Tags: php, csv, curl

I am trying to download a csv file from a third party website that i have to login into and then go to a link and save a file. I am using php 5.3.24 for this client. I am able to run the php file and get a csv file saved to the correct path but the csv file is just the html file information not the csv that should be downloaded. I have read all of the Stack answers to previous questions on this topic, any thoughts as to what is going wrong or even how to debug better.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',"1");
require_once ('../db.php');


$conn = db_connect();
$username = trim($values["***"]);
$password = trim($values["****"]);
$loginUrl = 'https://***/login/login';
$filename = "direct.csv";
$day=485;
//init curl
$ch = curl_init();
$fileUrl='https://www.***.com/direct.csv';

//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Set the post parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user='.$username.'&pass='.$password);

//Handle cookies for the login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


//set the URL to the protected file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fileUrl );
$agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0 FirePHP/0.7.4';
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$store = curl_exec($ch);

//curl_close($ch);
//execute the request
$source = file_get_contents($fileUrl);


//save the data to disk
file_put_contents('/downloads/direct.csv', $source);

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the HTML you are downloading isn't a page that says something like "You must be logged in to view this content"?

Comment: Also, do they suggest you can log into it with CURL, and if so, are you confident the fields are `user` and `pass`?

Comment: When i copy the curl from the login page i get Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" --data "username=***&password=***", about the you must be logged in part...you have to be logged in to get to the download screen so i cant find out what it says if  not logged in

Comment: Wait... why are you setting up all that curl, just to turn around and do `file_get_contents` on the url? That might be where your issue lies.

Comment: if i take out everything after the cookie and before file_get_contents i get the same results